# I can't install the version of ruby i want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I'm trying to follow the instructions from this website. 
https://github.com/lewagon/setup/blob/master/macOS.md

I did the course, and it worked fine on my MacBook pro, however it's not working on my mac. I keep getting this when I try to put rbenv install 2.4.4 into the terminal:

```
➜  ~ rbenv install 2.4.4

ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.4.4.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.4.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.4.4...
ruby-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.6 using ruby-build 20180822)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/xp/klxg47b13z37040q9qskx_q80000gp/T/ruby-build.20180914070221.21380
Results logged to /var/folders/xp/klxg47b13z37040q9qskx_q80000gp/T/ruby-build.20180914070221.21380.log

Last 10 log lines:
translating probes probes.d
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
error: error reading '/dev/fd/8'
1 error generated.
clang: error: unable to remove file: Operation not permitted
dtrace: failed to compile script probes.d: Preprocessor failed to process input program
make: *** [probes.h] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

any help you can give me would be appreciated. I'm thinking of just wiping my mac and restoring it to factory settings and trying again.

Comment: Can you run this command ? `sudo chmod -s /usr/sbin/dtrace`

Comment: Are you using any anti virus software?

Comment: Disabling your anti virus is something you should try as well.

Answer (score 2):

As it was suggested in the comments you might need to pay attention to the antivirus
Though you are using rbenv, I've found the similar issue reported for rvm. The users also received the same exception as you. Maybe it can help you to get the idea how to fix it: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4313

The error for the reporter of that issue was, which is similar to yours:

```
error: error reading '/dev/fd/4'
1 error generated.
clang: error: unable to remove file: Operation not permitted
dtrace: failed to compile script probes.d: Preprocessor failed to process input program
make: *** [probes.h] Error 1
```

Comment: It worked! Disabling my antivirus fixed the issue. Thank you so much - I've been trying to resolve it by myself for days. Thank you again!

Comment: @JamesDouglas glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To check what your ruby in now

```
$Ruby -v
```

Update it to ruby version 2.4.4

```
$rvm list known
$rvm install 2.4.4
$rvm use 2.4.4 --default
$gem install bundler
```

Let me know if does that help!

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours with the same problem I found the solution here:

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4313

Try Disabling the real-time protection of your anti-virus during installation.
Worked for me.

I hope it helps